# Question about $\min(a,b)$ as a notation

Tags: notation

What does $\min(a,b)$ mean? Does it mean that it is the minimum of the interval $(a,b)$ or is it the smaller number of the two numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you google it? Google give us [this](https://www.math.ku.edu/mapleta/help/instructors/mergedProjects/Advanced_Authoring/advanced_authoring/algorithmic_variables/functions_and_arguments/max_and_min.htm).

Answer (score 3):

It is the smallest number of $a$ and $b$.

The interval $(a,b)$ does not admit a minimum. It admits an inferior bound, which is $a$, but no minimum, because $a\not\in (a,b)$.